# $http.post connection refused, due to violation of content security policy directive 'connect-src'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, content-security-policy

While making an angular $http post request from within a cordova app, I receive an error 
'Refused to connect to 'https://localhost:3000/verifyPerson' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://localhost:3000/*" '

Below is the post request in the controller

```
$http.post("https://localhost:3000/verifyPerson" ).then(
    function(response){
        console.log('http success response handler');
    },
    function(response){
        console.log('http error response handler  ' +response.status);  
    }
);
```

Below are the response headers set in my Node server for content security policy and access control:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.header("Content-Security-Policy", 
 "default-src 'self';
  script-src 'self';
  object-src 'none';
  img-src 'self';
  media-src 'self';
  frame-src 'none';
  font-src 'self' data:;
  connect-src 'self' https://localhost:3000/*;
  style-src 'self'");
  next();
});

app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});
```

Below are the access origin and allow-navigation tags in the config.xml file for the cordova app.

```
 <access origin="http://localhost:3000/*" subdomains="true" /> 
 <allow-navigation href="http://localhost:3000/*" />
```

Below is the meta tag for content security policy in the associated html page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;connect-src https://localhost:3000/*;">
```

Could you let me know what I am missing for this post request to complete successfully?

Comment: Have you tried removing the wildcard like so: `connect-src https://localhost:3000;`?

Comment: Yes, I removed the wildcard like stated above, and also modified the access origin and allow-navigation tags in config.xml as below.         <access origin= " * " subdomains="true" /> 
 <allow-navigation href= " * " />  .   Now I receive a response.status of -1 (which is network request timed out) .

Comment: Which is a good sign: Your content security policy problem seems to be solved! What device are you testing on? Is the node webserver actually your `localhost`?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Appreciate it. It's the Nexus 5, device emulator. Yes, Node server is my localhost. . However I replaced cordova with the ionic framework and now I am able to make http get and post requests from android. So this question is resolved.